# File-path from xPath-Object or Document-Object in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Is there a way to get the path of a XML-Document from a xPath- or Document-Object in the xPath-API ?

That´s how the Objects are initalized:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\ExampleFile.xml"));

DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 

DocumentBuilder builder =  builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();                          

Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);

XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
```

---

**So the question is:**

Could the Objects `xmlDocument` or `xpath` somehow return `"C:\ExampleFile.xml"` ?

Comment: Are you looking for the actual children of the parent node?

Comment: @andrewdleach How do you mean that. Could you maybe clarify this question

Comment: NVM. I reread your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than creating a `FileInputStream` from the `File` and passing that to the `parse` method

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\ExampleFile.xml"));
```

use the version of `parse` that takes a `File` directly.

```
File file = new File("C:\\ExampleFile.xml");
// rest of your code is unchanged - parse(file) is now the
// java.io.File version rather than the InputStream version
```

When you pass just a stream the parser has no way of knowing that that stream was created from a file, as far as the parser is concerned that could be a stream you received from a web server, or a `ByteArrayInputStream`, or some other non-file source.  If you pass the `File` directly to `parse` then the parser will handle opening and closing the streams itself, and will be able to provide a meaningful URI to downstream components, and you'll get a sensible result from `xmlDocument.getDocumentURI()`.

As an aside, if you want XPath to work reliably then you need to enable namespaces by calling `builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true)` before you call `newDocumentBuilder()`.  Even if your XML doesn't actually use any namespaces, you still need to parse with a namespace-aware DOM parser.

Comment: Could you maybe show me some code in which you can show what you mean exactly ? That would be nice

Answer (score 1):

Using the Document object xmlDocument you can return the path of the file with:

```
xmlDocument.getDocumentURI();
```

Comment: Does your file actually exist? Silly question, but let's backtrack

Comment: Yeah sure. But for all files it returns me `null`